# Necesito eliminar un producto de la base de datos

Tags: mysql

```
<?php


require_once("../Modell/ModelProducto.php");
$enlace= new Producto();


$resultado=$enlace->mostrarTodasProductos();

while($fila=$resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>".$fila['id']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$fila['nombre']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$fila['precio']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$fila['stock']."</td>";
 echo "<td>".$fila['descripcion']."</td>";
 echo "<td> <a href='../Controller/ControllerActualizarProducto.php?id=".$fila['id']."' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a>"
      ." - <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#ModalEliminar' onclick=enviarID(".$fila['id'].")>Eliminar</a>  </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
```

//Comentario ya que existe una identica para eliminar personas y elimino registro.... pero de eliminar productos no puedo me redirecciona al eliminar personas un ayuda por favor

Comment: Lo único que veo es que el href del boton de eliminar tiene un #, en vez de la direccion del controllador para eliminar

Comment: O bien tienes el problema dentro del código JS de la función `enviarID()`, si lo has copiado ¿estás eliminando una persona?, o dentro de PHP en la parte que recibe la petición para eliminar el registro